# In Sharepoint apps How do you skip "Do you trust this app" page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Is there a way to skip "Do you trust this app" page by giving authorizations before hand?

I did try to give app permissions like the one mentioned [here](https://help.appwise.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001189203-SharePoint-Online-configuration) but that did not work.

Comment: This function is designed to not be skip-able.

Comment: I see. We are using this for native app and this results to the unwanted behavior of showing trust page after MS login screen. Any other suggestions?